# How to maintain aspect ratio of the image by keeping contents over image with same padding

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV width an image in my footer which takes 100% width of the screen. I am not able to maintain the so called "aspect ratio" of the image as I stretch the browser window for smaller screens say 1366 it looks odd.

I think that's because I have content over the image which has padding top and bottom that simply stretches the image but I need this contents with same padding top and above as I have in my fiddle.

Here I have created a **[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/k0as46xd/)**. What CSS changes should I use to maintain the aspect ratio of the image for all screens.

```
<div class="membership-info-div ">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8 site-member-info-div">
        <h1 class="membership-title">MY title goes here</h1>
        <h2 class="membership-subTitle">My subtitle goes here</h2>
        <ul class=" membership-features-list ">
          <li>bla blab bla blab bla blab bla blabbla blabbla blab</li>
          <li>bla blabbla blabbla blabbla blabbla blabbla blabbla blab</li>
          <li>bla blabbla blabbla blabbla blabbla blabbla blabbla blab</li>
          <li>bla blabbla blabbla blabbla blab</li>
                 <li>bla blabbla blabbla blabbla blab<br>
              bla blabbla blabbla blabbla blabbla blab</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="account-div col-sm-12">
          <button class="btn btn-yellow custom-width-btn col-sm-4">Create an account</button>
          <h5 class="learn-more-txt col-sm-8" ><a href="">Learn more about site membership</a>&nbsp;&nbsp; <img src="images/arrow-left-wt.png" alt=""></h5>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.membership-info-div{

background-image:url('http://unplugged.ee/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/frank2.jpg');
width: 100%;
 /*    height: 422px; */

    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.site-member-info-div{
padding-top: 4%;
    padding-bottom: 8%;
}
.membership-title{
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 40px;
font-family: 'roboto';
font-weight: 700;
color: #ffffff;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
.membership-subTitle{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
font-size:26px;
color:#b8b8b8;
font-family: 'roboto';
font-weight: 700;
}
.learn-more-txt{    
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    color: white;
    padding-left: 0;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 58px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.account-div{
padding-right:0; 
padding-left:0;
    padding-top: 25px;
}
.membership-features-list{
    padding-left: 0px;
    list-style: none;

}
.membership-features-list li{
        width: 50%;
        float: left;
color: white;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: 'roboto';
font-weight: 700;
text-transform: uppercase;
background: url("../images/list-style-type.png") no-repeat left 5px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: The person who down voted please can you briefly explain what wrong with my question?

Comment: Putting a link in a code block is not the right way to bypass the code requirement of a question—given your reputation you should have known the rules on SO about asking a proper question by now. Please put the relevant code as part of your question.

Comment: I have created fiddle all the working code is there only, you want me to put all css and html here and mess with it?

Comment: The trick is to create a [**minimal, concrete and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We aren't here to pour through bulk of your code. Just reproduce your issue with a minimal setup, and that would be sufficient.

Comment: Have you seen my fiddle? do you think thats the bulk of code?

Comment: I hope the information is now sufficient @Terry sir, can you please suggest me any css trick with this?

Answer (score -1):

I am finding it difficult to understand what it is you are trying to ask of us, but from what i've gathered I would suggest removing whatever form of padding you are using and replace it with a new div with margins to contain your overlaying content on the image.

Padding can be extremely irritating to work with, in fact, as a designer i almost NEVER use padding, i create new divs within divs and control their margins, seeing as margins do not affect the actual width and height of the div, they prove to be much more elegant.

To solve your problem, edit the "membership-info-div " class div, to "membership-info-div" (Remove that extra space, it does my head in) and change the CSS to this:

```
.membership-info-div{
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image:url('http://unplugged.ee/wp-    content/uploads/2013/03/frank2.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100%;
}
```

Note: That should hide any extra vertical content of the image that extends further than the div, and the width should be contained to the window size. (Without stretching your image and making it look unnatural).

And hey, if you want to stylise it just that extra little bit, you might consider using:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

By doing that, users can scroll and the text or content in front of the image can move, this can help readability as the image and the content borders can often match in color, so scrolling can help users make sense of things a bit better.

That may solve your problem, but I can't be sure, seeing as you've given us a somewhat butchered version of whatever it is you are creating. The other solution I can offer is perhaps replacing the padding you've put on the site-membership-info-div and giving that value as a margin on the child of that class.

Other then that, try to give us a slightly better example of code (Unless that IS what you're actually working with, which is slightly frightening).